# Best way to multiply string by array

Tags: python, string, list

I want to repeat each character in my string by a number I have in an array i.e. if

```
rep = [1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
seq = 'AATCGGGAA'
```

I want something like

```
seq*rep
```

to output

```
ATCGGGA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest way to do this will be to use `map` with `operator.mul`:

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> ''.join(map(mul, seq, rep))
'ATCGGGA'
```

Comment: What do you mean by fastest, i.e. most efficient? least number of keystrokes?

Comment: Good find! I appreciate the diversity of answers one can get from SO

Comment: So which one wins if you user [`itertools.izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) (or just regular `zip` in python 3)?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> rep = [1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
>>> seq = 'AATCGGGAA'
>>>
>>> list(zip(seq, rep)) # zip pairs up the items in the two lists
[('A', 1), ('A', 0), ('T', 1), ('C', 1), ('G', 3), ('G', 0), ('G', 0), ('A', 1), ('A', 0)]
>>>
>>> ''.join([x*y for x,y in zip(seq, rep)])
'ATCGGGA'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
"".join([s*r for r, s in zip(rep, seq)])
```

Output:

```
"ATCGGGA"
```

Comment: @iCodez beat you to it :) thanks for the answer though